# How do I debug a single line function in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is there a way in Visual Studio to debug a function which is only one line?

Something like:

```
int foo(int a) { return a + 1; }
```

It seems when VS enters the function, none of the data has been properly initialized, and upon inspecting the variable 'a', I get garbage data. The data is usually initialized once I step to the next line, but since this is a one line function it never seems to do that, which is quite annoying (as I will need to recompile everything just to inspect the value of a).

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint after the function call instead of where it's declared?

Comment: I guess that's good enough, although there may be a case where this may not be good enough, but I imagine it would be rare enough to not matter.

Comment: Single line function... might also be 3 line function (depends on the codestyle...and I prefer the latter one). But anyway, it makes no difference how the source code was written ... if you don't have it. What are you trying to debug? Do you have any _.pdb_ files? Is this function defined in a _.dll_ that you're calling? If no more info is available I'm afraid you 'll have to dig in (compiler generated) assembly code.

Comment: Using step into (F11) usually works for me, although I admit single line functions are not always easy for the debugger to handle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is simple function, you could start debugging and press `Alt+8` for assembly code debug

Comment: Update for VS 2022: The method still works, but not the keyboard shortcut. Either use `Debug` -> `Windows` -> `Disassembly` or `Ctrl`-`Alt`-`D`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you can step instruction-wise instead of linewise but why don't you just reformat it as

```
int foo(int a)
{
    return a + 1;
}
```

Comment: If I don't have access to the code, then I am unable to do this.

Comment: If it's a black box and the post conditions aren't as advertised, you should probably call the original developer.  Can you put the problem into context a little?

Comment: @Andrew If you don't have access to the code, you won't be able to see it, neither debug it. You can always edit source files and re-compile. Your question does not include much context about possibilities.

Comment: Andrew stated in the question that he doesn't want to need to recompile any code. (This answer is painfully obvious, regardless.)

Comment: This doesn't qualify as an answer to the question (even if the question is incomplete).